# Wordpress: change heading list names in post editing section

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Okay, it's a long shot but bear with me. I'm customizing a wordpress template for a friend and I want to make things as easy as possible for her while encouraging the use of the text hierarchy.

So, in the post editing section of the dashboard there is a dropdown menu with all of the available headings from `<h1>` to `<h6>`, plus the paragraph. Is there a way for that dropdown menu to display different names for each (or some) heading? Just for the user's convenience and with no effect in the headings style (which I know can be altered via the css file).

**TLDR: can I change the heading name in the drop list menu in wordpress post edition section?**

Answer (score 0):

This is possible duplicate to:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141534/how-to-customize-tinymce4-in-wp-3-9-the-old-way-for-styles-and-formats-doesnt

You're mostly interested in the block_formats part to change namings and what is display there, you can also follow with custom formats.

```
function mce_mod( $init ) {
    $init['block_formats'] = 'Paragraph=p;Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4';

    $style_formats = array (
        array( 'title' => 'Bold text', 'inline' => 'b' ),
        array( 'title' => 'Red text', 'inline' => 'span', 'styles' => array( 'color' => '#ff0000' ) ),
        array( 'title' => 'Red header', 'block' => 'h1', 'styles' => array( 'color' => '#ff0000' ) ),
        array( 'title' => 'Example 1', 'inline' => 'span', 'classes' => 'example1' ),
        array( 'title' => 'Example 2', 'inline' => 'span', 'classes' => 'example2' )
    );

    $init['style_formats'] = json_encode( $style_formats );

    $init['style_formats_merge'] = false;
    return $init;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'mce_mod');
```

You'll find more info at WP docs here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles